# Email sent from VPS going into spam folder or being blocked

Tags: email, hosting, vps, email-validation, email-client

I've recently purchased a VPS and have setup my websites including SPF and DKIM (both passed). I've ran the mail server (and website) IP through several blacklist checkers and nothing.

I've set the hostname correctly (I think I have anyway) but emails still seem to find their way into peoples spam folder (even testing emails) the emails do not contain spammy words I've actually tested emails to my mum and still the same.

Here is an email header - what do you think could be causing this:

```
Delivered-To: toricksshoes@gmail.com
Received: by 10.58.12.194 with SMTP id a2csp326429vec;
    Thu, 1 Aug 2013 05:36:40 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.60.97.1 with SMTP id dw1mr1074072oeb.1.1375360600533;
    Thu, 01 Aug 2013 05:36:40 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <ricky@builderstoolkit.co.uk>
Received: from se1.atroxxhosting.co.uk ([174.136.14.186])
    by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id c1si1447632oeq.153.2013.08.01.05.36.40
    for <toricksshoes@gmail.com>
    (version=TLSv1 cipher=RC4-SHA bits=128/128);
    Thu, 01 Aug 2013 05:36:40 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of ricky@builderstoolkit.co.uk designates     174.136.14.186 as permitted sender) client-ip=174.136.14.186;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
   spf=pass (google.com: domain of ricky@builderstoolkit.co.uk designates   174.136.14.186 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=ricky@builderstoolkit.co.uk;
   dkim=pass header.i=@builderstoolkit.co.uk
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/relaxed;   d=builderstoolkit.co.uk; s=default;
h=Message-ID:Subject:To:From:Date:Content-Transfer-Encoding:Content-Type:MIME-    Version; bh=WfUANWyObKlgHt0YFO0000p9rrW3lvnjXubb7xXJfGg=;
b=Csn9FoqU6zX2YHB95CaH6dqtLinradRgaPjJm8OXwvbECFco/zCJLCddZK4SBMcM3vpDd8Wp9Nwn+YE0w J+cEmI1bJNvu97Tp32wvvBK4mOeYqddJoLtsjfjtQqryMbvzLLvHlZk9nqwTz/IjrwgyWsfW5s3YdmLJq3LvKS7S3M=    ;
Received: from localhost ([127.0.0.1]:53993 helo=webmail.builderstoolkit.co.uk)
by se1.atroxxhosting.co.uk with esmtpa (Exim 4.80.1)
(envelope-from <ricky@builderstoolkit.co.uk>)
id 1V4s7U-0004R5-Uz
for toricksshoes@gmail.com; Thu, 01 Aug 2013 12:36:41 +0000
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8;
 format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

Comment: Sometimes exclamation points, large money figures or the word 'free' can trigger spam filters also...

Comment: Only having issues with Gmail.? try checking Gmail reputation for your mail server IP

Answer (score 2):

One reason why your messages may be going to the SPAM folder is the lack of a positive reputation.  Look at it from Gmail's perspective... about 80% of new sources of email are spewing malicious messages.  Often times Gmail and other mailbox providers look upon new sources of email as guilty until proven innocent.  ReturnPath, a email reputation company shows your IP as not having sent very much mail.  https://senderscore.org/lookup.php?lookup=174.136.14.186

By sending good mail to people who want to receive your messages your mail will begin to more often land in the inbox.  Your only other options are to play around with your content.  Try using different local address portions, domains, subjects, and content.  If you include URLs like bit.ly which is a domain commonly abused you could find this as the cause of your SPAM folder placement.

If all else fails just let one of the cloud email services deliver your messages on your behalf.  I've personally used SocketLabs with success on some past projects. http://socketlabs.com

Good luck resolving your issue!